# React route adds margin to the page

Tags: html, css, reactjs

This doesn't seem to make any sense, but I'll explain and add code.

Yesterday while working on my app I suddenly realized that there are unnecessary margins on the borders of the page. The type that would appear if you didn't reset the margin and padding.

I've tried eliminating things at the source, and noticed that I only get those margins once I add a route (doesn't matter which one). When there is no route, no margins.

I've tried checking one of the pages (maybe I've made some mistake in all of them) and after seeing no issue, I've decided to create a test page which is completely empty. If I add the route to that page, the margins appear. If I don't, they don't.
What could be the reason?

Attaching code below.

index.tsx

```
import React from "react";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { store } from "./store/store";
import { App } from "./App";
import "./styles.css";

const container = document.getElementById("root")!;
const root = createRoot(container);

root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

styles.css

```
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-family: Cabin;
}
```

App.tsx

```
import { Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Wrapper from "./wrapper";
import {
  TestPage,
} from "./pages";


export function App() {

  return (
    <Wrapper data-test="app">
      <Route path="/" element={<TestPage />} />
    </Wrapper>
  );
}
```

TestPage (it is import and rexported from an index.ts file, and again from the main "pages" index file. Those files are simply re-exporting the component below.

```
import { Box } from "rebass";
import { TestPresentational } from "../presentational";

export const TestContainer = () => {
  return <Box>Hola</Box>;
};
```

Just in case, this is my public index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta name="description" content="Web site created using create-react-app" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Cabin:wght@400;500;600;700&family=Open+Sans:wght@300;400;500;600;700;800&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Travel buddy</title>
</head>


<body>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_API_KEY&libraries=places"></script>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

EDIT:
It's been asked if it is possible the the Box component added the margins.
I've tried returning this from App.tsx instead of the wrapper component, and had no issues.

```
   return (
     <Box
       sx={{
         width: "100vw",
         height: "100vh",
         backgroundColor: "blue",
         margin: "0px",
         padding: "0px",
       }}
     ></Box>
   );
```

So no, the component is not the issue. An interesting thing that campe up though, is if I've returned that without commenting out the wrapper return (but making its code unreachable) I got the margins again.

Comment: Is possible that that Box component makes unwanted margin?

Comment: @ruckie No, checked with returning just a Box component in App.tsx and it was fine. I've added more details into my question (bottom)

Comment: You should use the browser inspector. It will tell you exactly where the margins are coming from.

Answer (score 0):

I had a new library that imported a css file that added padding to page. Found it thanks to @Andre suggestion (never got comfortable with the browser inspector but this forced me to, so glad it happened).